# Open stdout of new process as file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, pipe

Somewhere I've seen a method which lets you open the output of a program like a file. I vaguely remember that it involved opening a pseudo-filename which contains a pipe `|` symbol, but I was unable to find it on the internet. I think it looked something like this:

```
int fd = open("| some_program", O_RDONLY);
read(fd, buffer, 100);  // read 100 bytes of some_program output
```

This would:

1. Start `some_program` as a new process
2. Create a new pipe attached to the `stdout` of `some_program`
3. Return the other end of the pipe as a file descriptor

Does this method exist somewhere (maybe only in a specific language, not C) or did I just dream it up?

Comment: that looks more like something you'd see in a scripting language like Perl.

Comment: Did you mean `popen`?

Comment: Your dream is here: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html :-)

Comment: [https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html)